# Wget to sleep after first execution

Tags: php, codeigniter, command-line-interface, wget

I have this php exec line:

```
exec('wget http://myurllinktofunction?id='.$insert_id .' > /dev/null &');
```

This will trigger on a if condition, what I want to do is to make that wget call to sleep let's say 60s and all this time don't make any calls on that exec, also to be noted that I don't want my if condition when is true to wait for the sleep: I give you example:

```
if($weight>15000){
    $insert_id = $this->db->insert_id();
    exec('wget myurllinktofunction?id='.$insert_id .' > /dev/null &');
                                    }
    $this->_issue_success();
    break;
```

I want this flow in the $weight var I will get values, one at a time, let's say a list of values. When the condition $weight>15000 is TRUE execute my if and after that sleep my exec for 60s(that wget won't be executed for 60s) but finish the issue_success() ( I have the case OpResult::Ok;) no matter that exec is on sleep or not, I want to sleep only that part with exec but the if should continue but only don't acces the exec of it's on sleep, if it's not on sleep execute it again and do the same flow.

Comment: Just as a note, there are better ways of issuing a GET request that don't involve potential CLI injection like your code does. cURL could handle this, abeit with maybe one or two more lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

As much i understand this might be help you :

```
$timer = 0;
$seconds = 60;

if($weight>15000){
    $insert_id = $this->db->insert_id();

    for($i=0;$i<$seconds;$i++){
            sleep(1);
            $timer++;

            if($timer == 60){
                    exec('wget myurllinktofunction?id='.$insert_id .' > /dev/null &');
            }

            $this->_issue_success();
            break;
    }
}
```